# Force Desktop View on All devices Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to force Desktop view on all devices and just skip mobile and tablet styles entirely. This is because the desktop version just looks really good and the mobile version are not for my website. Also mobile view breaks a lot of stuff. Looking online this question has been asked many times but oddly, never answered. Is there a way to do this for a general template?

Answer (score 0):

In header.php in appearance -> edit theme in Wordpress 5.6, you can find the line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and delete it. This does not work in all themes, but for many it does work.

Comment: This is considered bad practice from an SEO POV as of 2020. @ https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/03/announcing-mobile-first-indexing-for

Comment: What's the solution, then?

Comment: Having a theme devlopped for mobile first.

Comment: Sorry but that's not a realistic solution for most people to just remake their entire website or to change template completely.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, it's not my website. It's way less work than what you think, not doing it will result in organic traffic fall off. Anyway, good luck.